# NLTK regex, how to write a specific grammar?

Tags: python, regex, nltk, chunking

am using Python and RegexpParser and i wanna write a grammar like this:

```
<JJ><NN><anything>
<RB><JJ><not NN nor NNT>
```

- the first one means: the first word should be a JJ, the second a NN, and the third anything
- the second one means: a RB followed by a JJ, and the third word shouldn't be NN nor NNT

I have difficult to express (nor, not...) in regex

...

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hey, you can see my answer, i hope it'll be more obvious to you

Answer (score 0):

for example below, the grammar is :

```
grammar = """ P: {<NN><VBD><JJ><CC><JJ>}
                    {<NN><VBD><JJ>} 
             """
```

The chunker:

```
PChunker = RegexpParser(grammar)
```

The sentence is:

```
sentence = ['The', 'pizza', 'was', 'good', 'but', 'pasta', 'was', 'bad']
```

after running the code below:

```
print("sentence : ",PChunker.parse(pos_tag(sentence)))
```

The result will be :

```
sentence :  (S
              The/DT
              (P pizza/NN was/VBD good/JJ)
              but/CC
              (P pasta/NN was/VBD bad/JJ))
```

in my case, i wanna write a grammar as mentioned below : 
[image]